# Use @RequestBody to map JSON to a class with @Builder

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am using `@RequestBody` to map JSON body of a POST request to my java class. My POST request was working fine initially, but when I add the `@Builder` annotation to my java class it started fail. I was wandering how I can use `@RequestBody` to map JSON to a class with @Builder annotation

My Controller Class

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/cards/add" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void addCard(final HttpServletResponse response, @RequestBody Card request) {
    ...
}
```

My Model Class

```
@Data
@Builder
public class Card {

    private String Id;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding these:

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Card {

    private String Id;
    ...
}
```